# Bootstrap Carousel - Next Container Not Visible

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

The container ('fifth-block' in my code) must go after my carousel (situated in 'fourth-block'). But the container is under the carousel. When reloading the page or scrolling the carousel, it is noticeable.

https://jsfiddle.net/l_zemlyanaya/9dxaxusm/4/

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="fourth-block">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/carousel-alyona.jpg" alt="Chania">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/carousel-lera.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/carousel-lesya.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fifth-block container-fluid">
    <p class="proof-text">SOME TEXT</p>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
    .fourth-block {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}

 #myCarousel {
 height: 300px;
 }

 fifth-block {
 background: #F2EADC;
 padding-top: 30px;
 height: 200px;
 background-image: url("../images/pic3.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 }

.proof-text {
font-family: SummerFontLight;
font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @AllDani https://jsfiddle.net/l_zemlyanaya/9dxaxusm/4/

Comment: @AllDani it is not noticeable in Jsfiddle but the fifth-block is under the fourth-block when the HTML file is opened directly in browser

Comment: The jsfiddle is no longer loading for me..

Comment: @AllDani the solution was to put the carousel in the <header></header>... it works nice now

Comment: @AllDani i don't know why it is not loaded for you.. just checked it out, all works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel should have been put in header